# crash_info_entry_0: CoreUI: deallocating _CUIInternalLinkRendition ... Assets.car

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

When inspecting a crash with Firebase Crashlytics, I noticed the following line in the Keys section:

> CoreUI: deallocating _CUIInternalLinkRendition 7113 /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1E06D0B4-30EA-41CA-998C-D8E86AA94100/.app/Assets.car

Is this related to the assets in my app? A memory issue in CoreUI?

Comment: did u found the solution ?

Comment: I have same problem

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: I am also getting same issue, if anyone got solution please help me.

Comment: I am facing this crash on my cordova ios app. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Any solution? we are getting same issue..

Answer (score 1):

I have a player and the crash happened when I was force removing a time observer from the player. But the timeObserverToken is nil.

#### The Fix: Just unwrap token with `if let` before using!

```
func endPlayerObserving () {
   //BAD CODING, Don't ever force unwrap optional objects
    player?.removeTimeObserver(timeObserverToken!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it probably happened when force unwrapped a referenced property (UI - specifically UITextField) of a different class. It was nil (probably some threading, view deallocation issue)

Answer (score 0):

For my unity project, the crash has gone away after decreasing the sizes of all textures in the project. I had an 8k by 8k skybox used, so this might have been the source of the problem (**I don't have a way to test it, so it's just a guess**).